# How to stop a time.Timer that is currently being listened to in another go-routine?

Tags: go, timer

I have an *idle timeout* timer being `select`ed on in a goroutine, if I see activity I want to cancel the timer.

I had a look at [the documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Timer.Stop) and I'm not positive I'm clear on what it says.

> `func (t *Timer) Stop() bool`
>   Stop prevents the Timer from firing. It returns true if the call stops the timer, false if the timer has already expired or been stopped. Stop does not close the channel, to prevent a read from the channel succeeding incorrectly.
>
> To prevent a timer created with NewTimer from firing after a call to Stop, check the return value and drain the channel. For example, assuming the program has not received from t.C already:
>
> `if !t.Stop() {
>       <-t.C
>   }`
>
> This cannot be done concurrent to other receives from the Timer's channel.

I'm trying to understand when I have to drain the channel manually.

I'll list my understanding and if I'm wrong please correct me.

If `Stop` returned `false` this means either:

- The timer was already stopped

  - In this case, reading from the channel will block so I shouldn't do it
- The timer was already expired

  - Since I have another goroutine listening on the channel, can I know for certain if it has received the event?
  - From the *"this cannot be done concurrent to other receives"* part of the documentation it appears that this isn't an option, so what should I do?

In my case getting a superfluous event from the timer is no big deal, does that inform what I should do here?

Comment: Please see [this](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/14383) and the discussion linked from [a comment](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/14383#issuecomment-220655783) there.

Comment: Can you describe your *original problem* in more detail? I'm asking because having more background might enable suggesting more options—such as passing the listening goroutine a `context.Context` with a deadline set, and then cancelling it from the outside, if needed.

Comment: Why? Why would you need to stop a timer in a different routine? Why not pass in a context that you can cancel. There's the `select` construct and a `context.WithCancel` just for that...

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem, I've recently started working in [tag:go], I haven't heard of `context.WithCancel`, thanks for pointing it out. I later thought of a way to solve my problem in a more idiomatic way that doesn't involve handling a timer in separate routines.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason that you might need to drain the channel is because of how goroutines are scheduled.

**Problem**

Imagine this case:

1. Created a timer
2. Timer fires, sending a value to `t.C`
3. Nothing has received / read the value yet, but `t.Stop()` is called.

In this case there is a value on the channel `t.C`, and `t.Stop()` returns false because "the timer already expired" (i.e. when it sent the value on `t.C`).

The reason that the docs say "this cannot be done concurrent to other receives" is because there's not guarantee of ordering between the `if !t.Stop {` and the `<-t.C`. The stop command could return false, entering the if body. And then another goroutine could be scheduled and read the value from `t.C` that the body of the if statement was trying to drain. This would cause a datarace and result in blocking inside the if statement. (as you pointed out in your question!)

**Solution**

It depends on what the behaviour of the thing listening to the timer is.

If you are just in a simple select:

```
select {
    case result <- doWork():
    case <-t.C
}
```

Something like above. One of a few things could happen:

1. The work could be done from `doWork`, sending the result, all good.
2. The timer could fire, causing the timeout, breaking the select.
3. Call to stop, stop the timer, only way out of the select is `doWork()` completing.
4. The timer could fire, another routine calls `t.Stop()`, but it's too
   late because the value has been sent, causing the timeout, breaking
   the select.

As long as you are OK with case 4, you do not need to interact / drain the channel after calling `Stop.`

If you are not OK with case 4. You still cannot drain the `t.C` channel because there's another goroutine listening to it. This could block in the if statement. Instead you must find another way of laying out the code, or ensuring that your goroutine in the select is not still listening on the channel.

Comment: Thanks, luckily I'm OK with #4 otherwise I would have to do some actual work :)